# How can I use JavaScript's replace function to divide a matched number by 100?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to divide a regex-matched number in string format by 100 within JavaScript's `replace` function:

```
var number = "4354543"; 
var result = number.replace(/(\d+)/, '$1/100');
console.log(result);  -> Printing 4354543/100
```

The answer should be `43545.43`, but instead I'm getting `"4354543/100"`.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: regex is only for string manipulation. Why can't you use `/` operator after converting the `number` variable to string.

Comment: No, why do you think it would be? Regexes are for string manipulation. What you did was replace the string with a different string that _happens_ to look like division.

Comment: I think you're making this too complicated. You don't use regex for math.

Comment: `console.log(eval(result))` will do it but google `eval()`

Comment: To be consistent with other scenarios, I need to use regex.

Comment: @SaiGiridhar I've completely reworded your question. Hopefully this will clear up any confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I got the answer down

Comment: number.replace(/(\d+)(\d{2}).(\d*)/, '$1.$2$3'); It works for decimal number too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the input strings are at least 3 digits, a simple solution is to insert a decimal separator before the last 2 digits.

```js
var number = "4354543"; 
var result = number.replace(/(\d+)(\d{2})/, '$1.$2');
console.log(result);
```

However, using a function as the second argument to `.replace`, as [the answer by James Thorpe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40529030/6738706) does, gives you more flexibility.

Comment: This is a good answer too - based on the OPs comment that _"To be consistent with other scenarios, I need to use regex"_, he may not be able to use a callback function - this answer would address that.

Comment: Nice alternative solution.

Comment: Still better answer will be number.replace(/(\d+)(\d{2}).(\d*)/, '$1.$2$3'); It works for decimal number too

Comment: @SaiGiridhar, Unfortunately, `number.replace(/(\d+)(\d{2}).(\d*)/, '$1.$2$3')` does not work on your original example, `number = "4354543"`.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* use regular expressions for this, if that's what you're really after - for instance, lets say you want to divide numbers in a larger string by 100.  To do this, you have to use the function callback, which lets you manipulate the captured groups in more complex ways:

```
var number = "abc 4354543 xyz"; 
var result = number.replace(/\d+/g, function(val) {
    return +val/100;
});
console.log(result);  //abc 43545.43 xyz
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an almost identical answer. I think OP simply phrased their question incorrectly, and probably meant to write something like: *how can I use JavaScript's replace function to divide a matched number by 100?*

Comment: I wouldn't call this "using regular expressions". I associate this phrase with _regular expressions_ only. Using the output of one is a tad different. By the same token, you can use regex for _literally_ everything...if by that you don't mean the regular expression, nor the engine.

Comment: Yes you can but is it usefull to trickily use *Regexp* when you can use simple *ParseInt*?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I'm basing my answer on the angle that there's something missing in the OPs question - ie the fact it may be part of a larger string - covered in my opening sentence.

Comment: I wrote a similar code long before this answer was posted, but I do not answer unclear questions. Also, there is no point in using a capturing group if you are not passing it to the anonymous method. Use `/\d+/g` - no capturing group and a global modifier to replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion in your mind about what regex can do.

In your case you really don't need regex. Just do

```
var number = "4354543";
console.log(number/100);
```

You will see what you expect, js will change string to number(don't worry)

Answer (score 0):

**Regexp** are not suitable for mathematic operations.

Use `Number` javascript class.

### In your case

```
 const number = '5485454845'; // Wathever
 const result = Number(number) / 100;
```

Comment: It's better to use `Number(number)` than `parseInt`.

Comment: Why that? I rather prefer to use `parseInt` because it  require an explicit base. Like in C++, I prefer `static_cast<>` rather than `(int)` casts.

Comment: Because parseInt does some _odd_ stuff. For example, it will not parse exponential numbers correctly, e.g., `"1e7"` will be parsed as `1` but something that might actually be invalid, such as `1abc7` will...also be parsed as `1`. `Number("1e7")` and `Number("1abc7")` will be _understood_ rather than simply parsed and will resolve to `10000000` and `NaN` respectively. `parseInt` is useful if you have a string that _starts_ with numbers and you want to extract those, but for a string that _is_ a number, it's not the best tool.

Comment: ok, that's a valid point :) Thanks for the comment. I edit my answer. It's good to know for my personnal code, gonna change to that